# component won't render again although properties have changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I would like to create a simple "Conway's Game of Life" application and store the settings that have already been made to the localStorage.

I created three views

- Map Settings
  | Define map size etc.
- Map Setup
  | Create a preset for your map
- Map Launch
  | Launch your preset

Whenever the settings change the preset has to be deleted because the preset might have a different old size. The settings use default values if the localStorage is empty.

Within my store I save the map setup to the `grid` property. So the value is either `null` or a two dimensional array from the localStorage.

When routing to the *MapSetup.vue* file I use the mounted event to setup the preset

```
  mounted: function() {
    if (this.grid) { // the preset from the store / localStorage
      this.currentGrid = this.grid; // use the preset
    } else {
      this.currentGrid = this.generateNewMap(); // generate a new preset
    }
  }
```

`this.currentGrid` could have a size of 50x50 for example. I created a working example of my application here

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-vuex-and-vuerouter-h6yqu

You can define the settings in *MapSettings.vue* and the `grid` state from mapSetup should be set to `null`. After redirecting to *MapSetup.vue* no grid should appear but if you debug `this.currentGrid` there should be a two dimensional grid that should be rendered.

Why does the card remain empty and won't "draw" a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing prop when instantiating the `SetupRow` component in `SetupGrid.vue`.  `SetupRow` expects the following props but `row` is not being passed:

```js
props: {
  row: Array,
  rowIndex: Number
}
```

It should look like this (with `row` prop included):

```html
<SetupRow
  v-for="(row, rowIndex) in grid"
  :key="rowIndex"
  :row="row"
  :rowIndex="rowIndex"
  @rowClicked="onRowClicked"
/>
```

One way to avoid this in the future is to define your props with a `required` property like the following.  This will generate an error if the prop is not passed:

```js
props: {
  row: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  rowIndex: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
}
```